# consistency strength

Tags: logic

I am just beginning to read about consistency strength, and wondered if someone could clarify the relation between a two kinds of claims that I'm encountering.

(1) A theory, T, proves the consistency of another, T* -- i.e., T |- Con(T*)

(2) We can prove that if T is consistent, then so is T* -- i.e., we can prove Con(T) --> Con(T*)

Does (1) imply (2), or conversely?  How, precisely, does one argue for each claim?

Comment: (1) implies (2), but (2) doesn't necessarily imply (1). Our proof that consistency of $T$ implies that of $T^*$ is carried out in the metatheory, using any tools and theorems we have (all of mathematics, to date), but $T$ might not be strong enough to prove the consistency of $T^*$, or of any other theory, for that matter. For a theory to be able to prove consistency of a(nother) theory $T^*$, it has to be able to "talk about" many things: the syntax of $T^*$, what a proof is, etc. This presupposes that $T$ contains a sufficient amount of arithmetic (or the equivalent) to express such things.

Comment: @BrianO: Is that supposed to be an argument that (1) implies (2)? I cannot quite follow it.

Comment: @HenningMakholm No, not at all. After the first sentence, everything else is about (2) implying (1) — or not.

Comment: Thanks very much.  Does it even happen that in one theory we can prove Con(T) --> Con(T*) and in another we can prove Con(T) & ~Con(T*)?  Also, the claim that T |- Con(T*) does not depend on our metatheory, right (so long as it is classically consistent, and we can talk about logical implication)?

Comment: ("Even" should be "ever", in case that wasn't clear.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(2) does not imply (1), because we could take $T$ and $T^*$ both to be $PA$. Then, trivially, Con(PA) implies Con(PA), but we know that PA does not *prove* Con(PA).

(1) will imply (2) given a few additional assumptions about $T$, such as the assumption that $T$ proves all true sentences of primitive recursive arithmetic. Then $\mathit{Con}(T^*)$ can be expressed as an arithmetic statement saying that a certain primitive recursive function is identically zero, and if $T$ proves this *and* is consistent, then the function in question *will* be identically zero on the standard naturals, so $T^*$ is actually consistent.

On the other hand, if $T$ is just some random theory in the language of arithmetic, then I don't think (1) would necessarily imply (2). For example $T^*$ could be some known inconsistent theory, and $T$ could consist of the single axiom $\mathit{Con}(T^*)$ -- but of $T$ doesn't even contain axioms that fix how $+$ and $\cdot$ work, then this could easily be consistent.

Comment: Thank you!  That's very helpful.